# What is meant by the requirement for an "outstanding academic record"?

Tags: phd

I am going to apply for a PhD program. What does mean when one requirement is "Outstanding academic record".

Comment: This is probably too hard to answer.   What discipline? what university?

Answer (score 9):

That means you have to have demonstrated that you're a really good student. Your "academic record" is what your undergraduate career says about you (transcripts, letters of reference, publications, awards). It must be "outstanding" - top of the heap.

Only very select schools (or those that think very well of themselves) can ask this explicitly of their applicants, though many require it.

Comment: I like and strongly agree with "those that think very well of themselves"

Comment: @Younes Or maybe "those that think too well of themselves" :)

Answer (score 2):

- Have you (co-)published a peer-reviewed article?
- Have you presented at a scholarly conference?
- Have you served as a research assistant?
- Have you served as a teaching assistant?
- Have you won any prizes, grants and awards for your studies?
- Have you had exceptionally good grades?
- Have you shown community engagement for your fellow students?
- Have you attended voluntary, extracurricular, academic activities (e.g., summer schools in Europe)?

If the response to any of the question is yes, then list it.

Comment: Have you got an especially good relationship with a few professors?

Comment: *Have you attended summer schools?* --- Perhaps reword this slightly? In the US this is a route often taken by students who failed a course during the Fall or Spring semesters.

Comment: Thank you, @DaveLRenfro, I changed it to "voluntary, extracurricular, academic activities". I didn't know about the U.S. connotation regarding summer schools.